# how to set multi level sudomaining in apache

Tags: domain, subdomain, godaddy

I have a VPS with valid IP, in godaddy I set a subdomain to it, `dev.mydomain.com` ,I want to have  some subdomain in this sub domain, I mean multi level subdomaining , as example I want to have  `site1.dev.mydomain.com`  and `site2.dev.mydomain.com`.

**I want to know is  possible that we handle this subdomains without set DNS for them in godaddy and handle  level 2 subdomaining only with apache in  VPS?**

and if I set a wildcard subdomain in goddady , I mean `*.dev.mydomain.com` then is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, in general you need DNS entries (at least one wildcard entry as per your comment) so that the clients know where to look when they call the domain name.

Only for strictly local dev purposes, you might get away with defining entries in your `hosts` file on the client. This would need to be done on every client and usually don't work on mobile devices where you can't always make this setting.

Comment: tnx for you attention, so if I set wildcard submomain in godaddy? I mean  set a record for `*.dev.mydomain.com`, then it is possible now?

Comment: Yes, that would work.